# Change Label Control Property Based on Data from SqlDataSource Inside a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater, sqldatasource

I am using a repeater control to populate data from SqlDataSource into my custom designed display-box.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBinding="Repeater_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>

</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>

   <div class="bubble-content">
     <div style="float: left;">
       <h2 class="bubble-content-title"><%# Eval("CommentTitle") %></h2>
     </div>

     <div style="text-align: right;">
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_category" runat="server" Text=""><%# Eval("CommentType") %> 
       </asp:Label>
     </div>

     <div style="float: left;">
       <p><%# Eval("CommentContent") %></p>
     </div>
   </div>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="mySqlDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CommentTitle],[CommentType],[CommentContent] FROM [Comments] WHERE ([PostId] = @PostId)">
   <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PostId" QueryStringField="id" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, there can be three types of "CommentTypes" in the database. I want to change the CssClass property of "lbl_category" based on the value of [CommentType].

I tried doing this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_category" runat="server" CssClass="<%# Eval("CommentType") %>" Text=""><%# Eval("CommentType") %></asp:Label>
```

But this gives an error: "The server control is not well formed"
and haven't been able to find a way to achieve this in the code behind. Can someone please help?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaning your code from this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_category" runat="server" CssClass="<%# Eval("CommentType") %>"
```

to this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_category" runat="server" CssClass='<%# Eval("CommentType") %>' />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm :)
It can keep me going for now but I would like to know if there's any way to the same in C#. Like I see what is the value and then change the control's properties accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the OnItemBound event.